# Сократить ссылку

Tags: url, php

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста сделать сокращение ссылки на PHP, вот к пример ссылка:

http://site.ru/index.php?id=1&topic=56&user=560&date=1234567890

Вот мне нужно обрезать её до 30 символов(чтобы её длина была 30 символов) и в конце добавить 3 точки. Как это можно реализовать на PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$url = "http://site.ru/index.php?id=1&topic=56&user=560&date=1234567890";
$short_url = substr($url, 0, 30)."...";
```

или это слишком просто?